# linear transformation, is diagonalizable? all values of a?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, transformation, diagonalization, tridiagonal-matrices

People i have the next problem.
Let $f: \mathbb R_3 → \mathbb R_3$ be the linear transformation such that https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLTqd.png with $\mathcal B = \{(1,0, −1), (0,0,1), (0,1 , 0)\}$. The set of all values of $a \in \mathbb R$ such that $f$ is diagonalizable is....
and they give me a few options:

1)$\mathbb R−\{−2\}$

2)$\{−4\}$

3)$\mathbb R−\{−4\}$

4)$\{−2\}$

I have started to diagonalize the matrix, but when I try to diagonalize I can't find the roots because there is a parameter:/

Comment: What do you mean with $M_{BE}(f)?$

Comment: @Senna MEB(f) is the matrix expression of the linear map f when one considers the basis E in the domain and the basis B in the target